# Extracting elements of population until two are equal

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given a population of n elements I take elements of it until I have taken two elements which are equal. I want to calculate the expected number of trials I need for this problem. Does this follow a concrete distribution?

Comment: You choose with replacement I take it?  And the original $n$ elements are distinct?

Comment: @lulu The original elements are distinct and you choose it with replacement

Comment: So, then the probability that the first $k$ you choose are distinct is $p_k=1\times \frac {n-1}n\times \cdots \times \frac {n-(k-1)}n$.  The probability that the first duplicate is observed on step $k$ is then $\psi_k=p_{k-1}\times \left( \frac {k-1}n \right)$.  Now you can just perform the sum.  (there is probably a simpler way to see the answer...but nothing is jumping to mind).

Comment: Possibly simpler variant:  Let $E_k$ denote the expected number of draws assuming you have seen $k$ distinct draws already.  Thus your desired answer is $E=E_0$.  We have $E_n=1$ and we have the recursion $$E_k=\frac kn \times 1+\frac {n-k}n\left(E_{k+1}+1\right)=\frac {n-k}nE_{k+1}+1$$